# Ext.mixin.Observable.on() / .un(): function reference not matching

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, listener

I am trying to add and remove listeners at runtime using `on()` and `un()` functions (aliases of `addListener` and `removeListener`).
I am taking the function reference from an instance of a component retrieved with Sencha's `getCmp()`

```
Ext.Viewport.on('orientationchange', Ext.getCmp('foo').handleOrientationChange, foo, {buffer: 50});
Ext.Viewport.un('orientationchange', Ext.getCmp('foo').handleOrientationChange);
```

From the sencha docs:

> un( eventName, fn, [scope], [options], [order] )
>
> The handler to remove. This must be a reference to the function passed
>   into the addListener call.

It's not clear to me why this isn't working. Clearly the second function reference does not match the first, but why is this happening? Shouldn't `Ext.getCmp('foo')` return the same object?

Comment: `getCmp` should return the same instance. Are you sure the problem is not elsewhere? What if you do `iHandler = Ext.getCmp('foo').handleOrientationChange` and give `iHandler` to both `on` and `un`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `removeListener` you also need to pass the same scope as specified in `addListener` then only the listener will be removed

```
Ext.Viewport.un('orientationchange', Ext.getCmp('foo').handleOrientationChange, foo);
```

---

```
scope : Object (optional)
The scope originally specified for the handler. It must be the same as the scope argument specified in the original call to addListener or the listener will not be removed.
```

Check:

[Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-removeListener)